# Files on the virtual box hard drive disappeared, how can I get them back?

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux

I have virtual box hosting arch linux. My Windows system crashed so I reinstalled Windows and everything on C: drive is gone. The virtual hard disk VDI file is on a external hard disk so it is kept. I try to recreate the virtual machine in virtual box using that same VDI as hard drive. When it's booting,it shows error messages like TSC calibration failed, /dev/sda2 clean, /dev/sda2 recovering journal etc. Eventually it finished booting and I can login use the old account. But everything is gone, home folder is empty, all the installed softwares disappeared. Where do all my files go? How can I get them back? I really appreciate any help. I do not want to spend 10 hours to install and configure everything.